# Vue2 composition API watch is not working

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I am new to Vue, so not sure what is wrong here.
I have setup a method that returns an object from a graphql call, this method looks like this:

```js
    import { useQuery, useResult } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
    import * as getCategoryBySlug from "@/graphql/api/query.category.gql";

    export function useGetCategory(slug: string) {
      const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(getCategoryBySlug, { slug });
      const category = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.getCategoryBySlug);
      return { category, loading, error };
    }
```

Then in my component, I set up this:

```js
    import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";

    import { useGetCategory } from "@/logic/get-category";

    export default defineComponent({
      name: "Categories",
      setup(_, context) {
        const slug = ref(context.root.$route.params.slug);
        const result = ref({});

        const getCategory = (s) => {
          const { category, loading, error } = useGetCategory(s);
          result.value = { category, loading, error };
        };

        onMounted(() => getCategory(slug.value));

        return { result };
      },
    });
```

Which I know is wrong, because I want to return `{ category, loading, error }` but I have no idea how to assign that from within the **getCategory** method.
Anyway, that issue asside, now I want to watch the **slug** to see if it changes (via route change), so I did this:

```js
    import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch } from "@vue/composition-api";

    import { useGetCategory } from "@/logic/get-category";

    export default defineComponent({
      name: "Categories",
      setup(_, context) {
        const slug = ref(context.root.$route.params.slug);
        const result = ref({});

        const getCategory = (s) => {
          const { category, loading, error } = useGetCategory(s);
          result.value = { category, loading, error };
        };

        watch(slug, () => getCategory);
        onMounted(() => getCategory(slug.value));

        return { result };
      },
    });
```

This didn't work. It compiles, but when I change routes, nothing happens. The view still shows the first result.
Here is the template:

```html
    <template>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            {{ result }}
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </template>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `watch(slug, () => getCategory);` will not call `getCategory` function on change but returns the `getCategory` function. Try this instead: `watch(slug, getCategory);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking around online and I found something allowed me to get it to work. I did this:

```
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch } from "@vue/composition-api";

import { useGetCategory } from "@/logic/get-category";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Categories",
  setup(_, context) {
    const slug = ref(context.root.$route.params.slug);
    const result = ref({});

    const getCategory = (slug) => {
      const { category, loading, error } = useGetCategory(slug);
      result.value = { category, loading, error };
    };

    watch(() => context.root.$route.params.slug, getCategory);
    onMounted(() => getCategory(slug.value));

    return { result };
  },
});
```